# jQuery events not firing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have been trying to get this to work. Basically I have a search box that has a default string in it (i.e. Search) and it should go away when the user clicks on the input field.

Here is the code:

HTML:

```
<form method="get" action="index.php" id="search">
<span id="searchLogo"></span>
<input type='text' name='q' id='searchBox' value="Search <?php print $row[0]?> tweets!" autocomplete="off" />
</form>
```

Javascript/jQuery: (defaultString is a global variable that has the value of the textbox)

```
function clearDefault() {
var element = $('#searchBox');

if(element.attr('value') == defaultString) {
    element.attr('value',"");
}
element.css('color','black');
}

$('#searchBox').focus(function() {
clearDefault();
});
```

Comment: Have you tried `element.val() == defaultString` and `element.val('')` (which is the only right way to access the value of a form element ;))?

Comment: I don't see any links between the two code snippets. You don't seem to call the clearDefault() function at all, there is no event binding to your input field that would take care of that.

Comment: @András Szepesházi Wouldn't the last 3 lines of code bind the focus event to the clearDefault() function?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem was that the event binding was not inside the $(document).ready() handler.

Fixed:

```
function clearDefault() {
var element = $('#searchBox');

if(element.val() == defaultString) {
element.val("");
}
element.css('color','black');
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#searchBox').focus(function() {
    clearDefault();
    });
});
```

Comment: +1 one for the correct solution  ;). But you really should use `val()` instead of `attr('value')`: http://api.jquery.com/val/

Answer (score 5):

Problem is here:

```
if(element.attr('value') == defaultString) {
    element.attr('value',"");
}
```

Change it with:

```
if(element.val() == defaultString) {
    element.val('value');
}
```

Update: Check it here:
http://jsfiddle.net/mr3T3/2/

Comment: This is not the problem. Works fine without using `val()`: http://jsfiddle.net/NN7w2/ (if course you should use `val()` but even then, the problem remains).

Comment: it works after putting the event inside an $(function() {...}); block...  What is the difference?

Comment: @alexBrand: Any code that should work on DOM elements should be put inside `$(function() {...});` (which is short for `$(document).ready()`). This ensures that the DOM is created and you can access the elements at the time the code is run. If you don't do this, your code runs *before* the elements exists and hence you cannot bind an event listener to them.

Comment: @alexBrand: Btw. you can add this (that you had to put it in the ready handler) as an answer and accept your own answer (as actually this is the only correct answer).

Answer (score 1):

It could be that event in fact is firing and your problem is in

```
if(element.attr('value') == defaultString) {
    element.attr('value',"");
}
```

is "defaultString" properly defined?

put a simple alert() inside clearDefaults() and see if the event works.

Answer (score 0):

i don't think **clearDefault** is reusable function, so don't create unnecessary function  for small block of code. See the following code sample, i added a small improvement in your functionality.

```
<form method="get" action="index.php" id="search">
<span id="searchLogo"></span>
<input type='text' name='q' id='searchBox' default="Search tweets!"  value="Search tweets!" autocomplete="off" />
</form>

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#searchBox").focus(function(e){
        var $this = $(this);
        if($this.val() == $this.attr('default')) $this.val('');
        else if($this.val().length == 0 ) $this.val($this.attr('default'));
    });
    $("#searchBox").blur(function(e){
        var $this = $(this);
        if($this.val().length == 0 ) $this.val($this.attr('default'));
    });
});
```

I added a **`default`** attribute to store default value and used it later on **`blur`** event.

See the example in [jsFiddler](http://jsfiddle.net/99fGQ/)