# External JS/jQuery files are loading but not executing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, flask

I am loading all of the below libraries and files, but for some reasons only the CSS is executing and none of the external js files.  The scripts.js file holds all of my jQuery and it seems to be formatted properly.  I'm not sure why the CSS would execute, but not the jQuery.

In chrome dev tools, everything below is loaded.

```
<head>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <meta charset=utf-8 />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/main.css') }}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/spectrum.css') }}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ url_for('static', filename='scripts/spectrum.js') }}"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ url_for('static', filename='scripts/scripts.js') }}"></script>
</head>
```

This is a portion of the scripts.js file:

```
$("span.output").draggable({
    stop: function(event, ui) {}
});

$('input[type=file]').change(
    function() {
        $('#submitbutton').click();
    });

$("#text_submit").submit(
    function(event) {
        $("#text1").html($("#1").val());
        $("#text2").html($("#2").val());
        $("#text3").html($("#3").val());
        $("#text4").html($("#4").val());
        $("#text5").html($("#5").val());
        $("#text6").html($("#6").val());
        $("#text7").html($("#7").val());
        $("#text8").html($("#8").val());
        $("#text9").html($("#9").val());
        $("#text10").html($("#10").val());
        $("#slider1").show();
        $("#slider2").show();
        $("#slider3").show();
        $("#slider4").show();
        $("#slider6").show();
        $("#slider7").show();
        $("#slider8").show();
        $("#slider9").show();

        event.preventDefault();
    });
```

Comment: Is the content of "{{" ... "}}" being evaluated? Is it possible your server / templating engine hasn't replaced the content there?

Comment: your doctype declaration is in the wrong place,  should be before everything else, can you show the actual rendered output, if that is the rendered output, then as Michael says your templates are not being rendered correctly.

Comment: @MichaelAaronSafyan yes that is flask templating, it is working properly because everything loads in dev tools.

Comment: is your js code being run in a domready function? like `jQuery(document).ready(Function(){});`

Comment: @PatrickEvans no it isn't.  should i wrap all of my jquery in what you  posted?

Comment: only that which needs to access and set dom events, as if you run it in the global scope the dom elements will not have rendered yet, so the events cannot be set.

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery events not firing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5129810/jquery-events-not-firing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put your code inside script.js in JQuery's Dom Ready function, like this;

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // Your code here
});
```

For more info, http://api.jquery.com/ready/

Answer (score 0):

Try the below, not declaring `type="text/javascript"` in your jquery loading way might also be an issue.

```
<head>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <meta charset=utf-8 />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/main.css') }}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/spectrum.css') }}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/spectrum.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/scripts.js"></script>
</head>
```