# javascript not working when added via asset pipeline

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I want to implement bootstrap themes to my rails application

http://startbootstrap.com/template-overviews/creative/

in that theme there is a file named creative.js

I have add it to my application via asset pipeline

and when I load the page and use inspect element I can see it under sources tab and I can open it

But the script not worked

but If I copy paste the code and put it in my html It worked properly

my application.js

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require creative
//= require_tree .
```

creative.js

```
(function($) {
      "use strict"; // Start of use strict

      // jQuery for page scrolling feature - requires jQuery Easing plugin
      $('a.page-scroll').bind('click', function(event) {
          var $anchor = $(this);
          $('html, body').stop().animate({
              scrollTop: ($($anchor.attr('href')).offset().top - 50)
          }, 1250, 'easeInOutExpo');
          event.preventDefault();
      });

      // Highlight the top nav as scrolling occurs
      $('body').scrollspy({
          target: '.navbar-fixed-top',
          offset: 51
      });

      // Closes the Responsive Menu on Menu Item Click
      $('.navbar-collapse ul li a').click(function() {
          $('.navbar-toggle:visible').click();
      });

      // Offset for Main Navigation
      $('#mainNav').affix({
          offset: {
              top: 100
          }
      })

      // Initialize and Configure Scroll Reveal Animation
      window.sr = ScrollReveal();
      sr.reveal('.sr-icons', {
          duration: 600,
          scale: 0.3,
          distance: '0px'
      }, 200);
      sr.reveal('.sr-button', {
          duration: 1000,
          delay: 200
      });
      sr.reveal('.sr-contact', {
          duration: 600,
          scale: 0.3,
          distance: '0px'
      }, 300);

      // Initialize and Configure Magnific Popup Lightbox Plugin
      $('.popup-gallery').magnificPopup({
          delegate: 'a',
          type: 'image',
          tLoading: 'Loading image #%curr%...',
          mainClass: 'mfp-img-mobile',
          gallery: {
              enabled: true,
              navigateByImgClick: true,
              preload: [0, 1] // Will preload 0 - before current, and 1 after the current image
          },
          image: {
              tError: '<a href="%url%">The image #%curr%</a> could not be loaded.'
          }
      });

  })(jQuery); // End of use strict
```

my application.html.erb

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <title>Creative - Start Bootstrap Theme</title>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>

    <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>

    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300italic,400italic,600italic,700italic,800italic,400,300,600,700,800' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Merriweather:400,300,300italic,400italic,700,700italic,900,900italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

    <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>

    <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
  </head>

  <body id="page-top">
    <%= yield %>
    <script>
      creative.js code here
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you see any js console errors when you load the script via the asset pipeline and load the page?

Comment: there is some error console but it's not the problem why the code not running, see my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change the firstline in creative.js seems to fix this problem

from 
`(function($) {` 
into 
`$(function() {`

and the last line from  `})(jQuery);` into `});`

[External JS/jQuery files are loading but not executing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21815460/external-js-jquery-files-are-loading-but-not-executing)

creative.js

```
$(function() {
    "use strict"; // Start of use strict

    // jQuery for page scrolling feature - requires jQuery Easing plugin
    $('a.page-scroll').bind('click', function(event) {
        var $anchor = $(this);
        $('html, body').stop().animate({
            scrollTop: ($($anchor.attr('href')).offset().top - 50)
        }, 1250, 'easeInOutExpo');
        event.preventDefault();
    });

    // Highlight the top nav as scrolling occurs
    $('body').scrollspy({
        target: '.navbar-fixed-top',
        offset: 51
    });

    // Closes the Responsive Menu on Menu Item Click
    $('.navbar-collapse ul li a').click(function() {
        $('.navbar-toggle:visible').click();
    });

    // Offset for Main Navigation
    $('#mainNav').affix({
        offset: {
            top: 100
        }
    })

    // Initialize and Configure Scroll Reveal Animation
    window.sr = ScrollReveal();
    sr.reveal('.sr-icons', {
        duration: 600,
        scale: 0.3,
        distance: '0px'
    }, 200);
    sr.reveal('.sr-button', {
        duration: 1000,
        delay: 200
    });
    sr.reveal('.sr-contact', {
        duration: 600,
        scale: 0.3,
        distance: '0px'
    }, 300);

    // Initialize and Configure Magnific Popup Lightbox Plugin
    $('.popup-gallery').magnificPopup({
        delegate: 'a',
        type: 'image',
        tLoading: 'Loading image #%curr%...',
        mainClass: 'mfp-img-mobile',
        gallery: {
            enabled: true,
            navigateByImgClick: true,
            preload: [0, 1] // Will preload 0 - before current, and 1 after the current image
        },
        image: {
            tError: '<a href="%url%">The image #%curr%</a> could not be loaded.'
        }
    });

}); // End of use strict
```